# C: uninitialized local variable takes on unexpected value

Tags: c

I'm really confused about the result of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int one(int a, int b) {
    int k, t;
    k = a - b;
    t = a + b + 1;
    if (k % 2 == 0) return t;
    else return 0;
}

int two(int x, int y) {
    int m;
    printf("%d\n", m);
    return m + x + y;
}

main() {
    int result = two(5, one(4, 3));
    // printf("%d\n", one(4, 3));
    printf("result is %d\n", result);
}
```

`one(4, 3)` returns 0, which is not surprising. But I don't understand why `two(5, 0)` returns 8. In other words, `m` takes on the value 3 without being initialized. How did this happen?

Comment: When you use an un-initialized variable, you are immediately transported to the realm of 'undefined behavior'. There's no telling what will happen.

Comment: Why is 8 unexpected? An uninitialized variable is allowed to contain any value, or worse, crash when you try to access it.

Comment: I was just wondering if `m` is 3 because 3 was passed in `one(4, 3)`. I expected `m` to be some random value.

Comment: 3 is a random number.

Answer (score 1):

C does not automatically initialize values to `0` when you define them. Technically, reading that data before you initialize it is undefined behavior. In practice, this normally results in a garbage value containing whatever data was stored in that location previously.

Comment: Yes. But why is `m` 3 instead of some other random value? Is this 3 the argument that was passed in `one(4, 3)`?

Comment: @HanZhu Probably because it reused memory that previously stored a `3`. at some point. It might or might not have been that particular 3.

Comment: Global variables will be initialized to zero

Comment: @e.jahandar actually just any static variable, whether it's global or not.